# for ... in with interface

Tags: delphi, interface, enumeration, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to go through a list of objects, but I just want to provide the interface implemented by my objects.

I have 2 cases: Just enumerating trough my list internally (which isn't that big of a problem, i could just use the object instead of the interface), and a property.

```
ITemplate = interface
  ...
end;

TTemplate = class (TInterfacedObject, ITemplate)
  ...
end;

TMyClass = class
strict private
  FTemplates: TObjectList<TTemplate>;
  function GetTemplates: IEnumerable<ITemplate>;
  ...
public
  property Templates: IEnumerable<ITemplate> read GetTemplates;

...

procedure TMyClass.LoopTroughInternally;
var
  template: ITemplate;
begin
  for template in FTemplates do  // isn't working, of course
    foobar(template);
end;

function TMyClass.GetTemplates: IEnumerable<ITemplate>;
begin
  // dunno what to do here...
end;
```

Is there a way to provide this enumerator without implementing a specific IEnumerable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken at face value, you can just change the local variable `template` to be of type `TTemplate` and then you are done. If this code is internal then there's no real need to do anything else.

However, you seem to me to have bigger problems.

```
type
  TTemplate = class(TInterfacedObject, ITemplate)
    ...
  end;

....

FTemplates: TObjectList<TTemplate>;
```

This is a big mistake. When you inherit from `TInterfacedObject` you are saying that the lifetime is managed by interface reference counting. That means that you must stop taking non-reference counted references. Because they are liable to become stale. And you are taking non-reference counted references when you use a `TTemplate` reference. You compound matters by using `TObjectList<T>` which is all about lifetime management.

The simple way to escape this is to use a list of interfaces rather than that `TObjectList<T>`.

```
FTemplates: TList<ITemplate>;
```

Now at this point you are done and dusted because you can indeed write

```
for template in FTemplates do
```

where `template` is `ITemplate`.

Comment: now that I see it.... \*facepalm\*
yeah, you are completly right, I shouldnt use the TObjectList
how did I even get htis idea :D
thx (: